# Micro ORM tools

Tags: orm

I have a client/project that I am working on and their solution is MASSIVE. using .NET 3.5/VS2008/MVC 2/EF/LINQ-SQL

problem is (well where do I begin?) that everything is overly abstracted out. It's causing alot of headaches just to create a new entity. creating a service repository, then a data repository, models, DTO's...list goes on.

One of the problems I currently faced was that if I need to do an IQueryable based on a related entity, then its not possible for LINQ-SQL to translate that code. I can't even begin to explain why its not possible.

Anyway, to cut to the chase - I've been given the task of finding a micro type ORM which is easily integratible into the solution, and that does the job right without all this hassle we are going through.

Now, we also need it so that it is possible for it to work with IQueryable scenarios and to pull up related objects/entities easily.

performance is another thing, currently its pretty slow but i do understand why. 
my mind is currently all over the place so apologies in advanced if I dont make much sense.

I see the Dapper has as good reputation. I am leaning towards it but how easy is for me to integrate into the solution of....

ASP.NET/Some top layer
Infrastructure/LINQ-SQL
DTO's
ServiceRepository
DataRepository

about 96% of the DTO's/Repos/Entity/whatever is all interfaced.

personally, I would have gone down the route of using DataReader and SPROCS/parsing out the results. But want something quick, clean (if possible) and less hassle.

I am emphasising IQueryable because, some sections on the website needs to search/filter through a LARGE table (histories). using the Telerik grid control gives us the flexibility of somewhat letting us construct the LINQ-SQL query before executing it. 
But one of the problems I mentioned earlier is just that - where LINQ-SQL cannot translate a scenario where there is a ViewModel containing flattened out data and perhaps a DTO which contains our related entity we need.

bleh. complicated! confused. I want to curl up and cry at times!

thanks for your responses (and comfort!)

Comment: dapper does not provide an IQueryable API (nor will most micro-ORM; the hint is the word "micro"). It is unclear what type of answer you are looking for really, other than a magic wand that somehow undoes restrictions imposed by your design.

Comment: Thanks Marc.yes, I kind of came to that conclusion after I had posted. Apologies - just this client solution such a head<insert bad word here>. So the problem that currently exists is that they have to create like literally 8-10 classes, each implementing an interface just to get a simple job done (such as GetById). The Repository layer and its interface. Then The ServiceLayer and its interface. Then extending the Entity class and adding an interface for that which then eventually gets returned to the controller (MVC) which then creates a ViewModel of that data in a flattened way.

Comment: too much over abstraction. I want to reduce that but at the same time be able to keep the IQueryable DataSource close as possible so its easy to query. Any thoughts? On another note - I swear im getting dumber working with this solution :-)

Comment: my main thought is that the way you have presented the question makes it hard to separate the technical question from what looks more like a gripe about project politics. SO can only help with one of those 2 problems. But generally, the easier to query (IQueryable etc), the worse the performance.

Comment: Thanks Marc. yes I apologise about that personally of the way the question was phrased. I guess there is too much going on over at this end and not enough time for it to settle for one to think and absorb!